# Sailsjs equivalent to expressjs app.param

Tags: express, sails.js, equivalent

I'm looking for an equivalent in sailsjs to this expressjs routing function:
http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param

I could not find anything, maybe I can trick by using the internal expressjs app instance?

Answer (score 0):

Sails 0.11 uses Express 3.16 as its router and middleware manager. So app.param is the correct function to use in sails.